# Changing current string value

Tags: javascript

how to change current value of a number, string or array?

```
String.prototype.change_me = function() { this = '123'; }
Number.prototype.change_me = function() { this = 123; }
Array.prototype.change_me = function() { this = [1,2,3]; }
x = '234';
x.change_me(); // error
x = 234;
x.change_me(); // error
x = [2,3,4];
x.change_me(); // error
```

the error is: ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

i think i have done this before, but i forgot how to do it..

Comment: Extending prototype is not usually a good idea.  For reading: http://blog.dreasgrech.com/2009/11/no-one-should-extend-objectprototype-in.html

Comment: @JoeMills extending the Prototype is totally fine.

Comment: String in many programming language (including JS) is immutable. Array is mutable with `push`, `shift`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I saw something like you want to do using the [apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) function, but seen for Objects not for these other types, not sure if its possible to use the same concept on String, Number and Array.